# Firing android intent from Android View Client

Tags: android, adb, androidviewclient

How can we fire an intent from AndroidViewClient ?
Can adb shell command be used to achieve it through AndroidViewClient?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what **Intent** you want to fire.

If you want to start an **Activity** there's support for it via `AdbClient.startActivity()`.

Otherwise, you can use `AdbClient.shell()` and invoke `am` to fire the Intent.